# what's wrong in this Ruby Dynamic variable code

Tags: ruby

Not sure what am I doing wrong here or missing.

```
avar = 'test'
test_bvar = 'passed'
finalanswer = send "#{avar}_bvar"
puts " #{finalanswer}"
```

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The `send` method is used to call a **method** by name programmatically. Since your `test_bvar` is not a method but a local variable, you need to refactor it like this:

```
def test_bvar
  "passed"
end

avar = "test"
finalanswer = send "#{avar}_bvar"
puts " #{finalanswer}"
```

Then you will reach your aim.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `test_bvar` as a local variable:

```
test_bvar = 'passed'
```

and you're trying to call it like a method:

```
send "test_bvar"
```

If you want to make this a method, do as @Mack94's answer suggests.